# Switching columns of a csv-file with awk

Tags: csv, awk

I would like to switch column 2 with 3 in a csv-file

```
cat test.csv
1,1;1,2;1,3
2,1;2,2;2,3
3,1;3,2;3,3
```

I tried it with:

`awk '{FS=";"; OFS=";"} { col1=$1;col2=$2;col3=$3; print col1,col3,col2 }' test.csv`

but it results in:

```
;;1;1,2;1,3
;2,22,3
;3,23,3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `BEGIN` before `{FS=";"; OFS=";"}`.

Comment: Thank you! `'BEGIN {FS=";"; OFS=";"} { col1=$1;col2=$2;col3=$3; print col1,col3,col2 }'` indeed works. Why is `BEGIN` necessary before the variables? I thought I would have defined them properly in my example above :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following may help you on same.

```
awk -F";" '{print $1,$3,$2}' OFS=";"   Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F";" '{gsub(.\r/,"");print $1,$3,$2}' OFS=";"   Input_file
```

In case your Input_file is having control M/carriage characters then use above code for same.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Well, I tried that before, but this resulted in the first line of the output being:
;1,21,3
Somehow there seems to be a problem with the file itself, because if I copy the content in a new empy text file everything works like expected. Very strange...I need to figure out what's "wrong" with the files I have

Comment: @MojoDodo, could you please see if your file has control M characters in it? by doing `cat -v Input_file`.

Comment: Indeed, `cat -v` results in `1,1;1,2;1,3^M` for the first line. I checked how to remove them and came up with `awk -F";" '{sub(/\r/,"")} {print $1,$3,$2}' OFS=";" testfile.csv` which works.
Never came across these control M characters before...Thanks for your help!
EDIT: just seen your edit above with the additional line.