# Swapping positions when reading a txt file

Tags: python, jupyter

I am reading a csv or txt file.

The csv or txt file has this format (can have several lines in the same format):

```
character , Int, character
```

And I want to change it to this format:

```
character , character , Int
```

and then save the new file as txt or csv.

I have this code to read a csv or txt file.

```
a_list=open(file)
for line in a_list:
  #line[1], line[2] = line[2], line[1] # Tried this line but didnt work
  print(line)
```

And I get this as result:

```
A,10,B
C,13,D
```

I want to change it to:

```
A,B,10
C,D,13
```

Whats the best way to do it?

**SOLUTION**

Using @DarrylG answer I changed the code to:

```
with open('edges.txt') as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    for line in mylist:
        line = line.split(',')              
        line[1], line[2] = line[2], line[1]  
        line = ','.join(line)               
        print(line)
```

Comment: I know you are looking to do this in Python, but if you have access to a Linux or MacOS shell you can [do this from the command line using `awk`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49170575/1717828)  If you don't need to use Python this might be easier: `awk -F"," '{print $1,$3,$2}' OFS="," filename.csv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable.  You need to split the line on comma to create a list whose elements can be changed.

**Revised Code**

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as a_list:       # It's recommended to use a context manager 
                                            #  rather than naked open
    for line in a_list:
        line = line.rstrip().split(',')     # Remove trailing '/n' and split on ',' 
                                            # creating a list
        line[1], line[2] = line[2], line[1] # Interchange list elements based upon index
        line = ','.join(line)               # re-constructs the string
        print(line)                         # show result
```

**Output**

```
A,B,10
C,D,13
```

Comment: I change the `s.split` to `a_list.split` but then i get `_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: just solved using you code as input.  I updated the question !

Comment: @StatsPy sorry, I updated my code.  I first played with a string called s, but did not completely update my code when I switched to a file.